# Now can I replace all Date classes?

Tags: c++, boost, c++11

I have big old C++ project. It has at least three Date and Time structures. They looks like:

```
struct Date {
  int day;
  int month;
  int year;
};

struct Time {
  int hour;
  int min;
  int second;
};
```

Some of them uses double, for Time::second, some of them have "optimization" and use short for `Time::(min, hour)` and `Date::(month, day)`.

So at now with new C++11 standard (and may be boost) is it possible to replace them with something that everyone uses?

I did look at `std::chrono`, but not see how I can use it.

For example, to illustrate what I want here test case:
I have a function, I give `Date` and coordinates to this function and it calculates when Sun rise and set and return two `Time` structures.

Comment: Would refactoring all your legacy code solve any particular problem?

Comment: At now we implement N + 1 version of our software. And it is hard to deal with all the same classes, but with different names. Like for some of them have operator- implementation, for other we have formating, one function accept this type of Time another accept another. A couple of time to calc something I need to just copy Time to Time 3 times.

Comment: `std::chrono` is for _times_ not _dates_. i.e. numbers of hours, minutes, seconds etc. relative to some other time, such as a given epoch, it doesn't tell you if a time is a Wednesday, or in July 2013.

Comment: Yes, and this is bad. Ordinary from my point of view situation: we want calc time when we going to reach point. We have speed, we have distance to it. So we take current time + distance / speed, and this the answer. But if at now 23:11 and you add 55 minutes. You should get the answer 00:06 tomorrow. Not 00:06 handle overlap yourself.

Comment: @JonathanWakely:  I've been working on some short and efficient algorithms with which `chrono` clients can use to tell if a `system_clock::time_point` is a Wednesday, or in July 2013.  http://home.roadrunner.com/~hinnant/date_algorithms.html  The weakest link in these algorithms is in automatically determining the current UTC offset.

Answer (score 3):

C++11 does not have a date class. There was one proposed (based on Boost.DateTime) for TR2, but that (TR2) was never finalized.

I would look at [Boost.DateTime](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/date_time.html) to see if it does what you want.

Comment: Thanks, I look at it. At now it looks danger. I am afraid of classes with timezone supports. I have bad experience with Qt QDateTime, it internally take my timezone and arithmetic with QDateTime gives very strange results, until I explicitly for each QDateTime instance set UTC.

Comment: `boost::posix_time::ptime` doesn't take "internally" anything.